# How to run commands on a secondary window from script

Tags: powershell

I'm taking the first steps on the PowerShell learning and for that reason my apologizes if what I'm going to ask is pretty basic.

I'm trying to run some commands on a remote computer with elevated privileges; for that I have a `script_1` that inside as an onliner that calls a `script_2` with the credentials (I admit that this may not be the best way to do it, but for commodity purposes for now I will this way).

But if I try to put any command in `script_1`, those do not run on the window with elevated privileges. I have no clue if doing this is possible and if possible how can that be done. I have searched here and on google but haven't found anything similar.

I really would appreciate some advice on how to manage this.

Edit:

the script I was trying to run is this

```
    $taskAction = New-ScheduledTaskAction `
        -Execute 'powershell.exe' `
        -Argument '-File C:\Desktop\Scripts\myscript.ps1'
    $taskAction
```

Comment: on the edit I put a comman I was trying to

Comment: There's no attempt to _execute_ anything in your code. `$taskAction` merely outputs the object describing the task action. Your question still lacks clarity, at least to me. (How is `script_1` executed remotely, what code is in which script, ...)